# Como envio dados de uma table html em POST de formulário?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, table

Tenho um formulário que contém uma lista dentro de uma tag **table**, como faço para enviar os dados dessa table no próprio **POST** do formulário? Sem utilizar inputs ocultos.
Se possível em Javascript puro, mas se não tiver jeito poderia ser em JQuery.

Comment: Coloque o código do formulário na pergunta, se possível...

Answer (score 2):

Isto dá uma ideia de como funciona. O que fiz foi aproveitar os atributos `data` e inseri nos botões para depois ir buscar com javascript:

```js
var editBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
for(var i=0;i<editBtns.length;i++){
 editBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var toPost = {};
    for(var key in this.dataset) {
        toPost[key] = this.dataset[key];
    }
    var queryString = '';
    for(key in toPost) {
        queryString += key + '=' + toPost[key] + '&';
    }
    queryString = queryString.slice(0, queryString.length - 1);
    console.log(queryString);
    enviar(queryString)
  });
}

function enviar(params) {
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "url.php";
  
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          alert(http.responseText);
      }
      else if (http.status == 404) {
       alert('not found');
      }
      else if(http.status >= 500) {
       alert('brrh');
      }
  }
  http.send(params);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    nome1
  </td>
  <td>
    email1
  </td>
  <td>
    endereço1
  </td>
  <td><button class="edit" data-endereco="endereco1" data-email="email1" data-nome="nome1" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    nome2
  </td>
  <td>
    email2
  </td>
  <td>
    endereço2
  </td>
  <td><button class="edit" data-endereco="endereco2" data-email="email2" data-nome="nome2">Enviar</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    nome3
  </td>
  <td>
    email3
  </td>
  <td>
    endereço3
  </td>
  <td><button class="edit" data-endereco="endereco3" data-email="email3" data-nome="nome3" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Enviar</button>
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
<br>
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0pwfnt/10/) no jsfiddle

Comment: Usando dataattributes já é mais limpo, mas não tem uma forma mais direta? Por exemplo, jogar os dados na querystring do POST?

Comment: Tem sempre de enviar os dados, pode ser com o submit normal do form como tenho aí, ou via ajax

Comment: Quero dizer jogar da tabela para a querystring direto, sem utilizar inputs, pelo que entendi aí você joga para os inputs e os valores dos inputs vão no submit, certo?

Comment: a tabela toda? Dessa maneira só com ajax

Comment: Coloquei uma nova resposta em baixo

Comment: Editei em cima para uma linha só e em baixo para toda a tabela

Comment: Blz @Miguel, valeu pela força, vou dar uma estudada e fazer uns testes, depois falo do resultado, muito obrigado, abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Veja por [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0pwfnt/8/) na consola, no jsfiddle. Desta maneira vai ter toda a tabela numa query string (clicar para enviar) pronta a enviar:

NOTA que deve ajustar as keys (data-campo) de cada um, para não serem repetidas

```js
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var toPost = [];
var toPush = {};
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   toPush = {};
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     toPush[row.cells[j].dataset.campo] = row.cells[j].innerHTML.trim();
   }
   toPost.push(toPush)
}
console.log(toPost);

var send = document.getElementById('enviar');
send.addEventListener('click', function() {
   queryString = '';
   for(var i in toPost) {
      for(var key in toPost[i])
      queryString += key + '=' + toPost[i][key] + '&';
  }
  queryString = queryString.slice(0, queryString.length - 1);
  console.log(queryString);
 enviar(queryString);
});

function enviar(toPost) {
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "url.php";
  
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          alert(http.responseText);
      }
      else if (http.status == 404) {
       alert('not found');
      }
      else if(http.status >= 500) {
       alert('brrh');
      }
  }
  http.send(toPost);
}
```

```html
<table id="mytab1">
<tr>
  <td data-campo="nome">
    nome1
  </td>
  <td data-campo="email">
    email1
  </td>
  <td data-campo="endereco">
    endereço1
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td data-campo="nome">
    nome2
  </td>
  <td data-campo="email">
    email2
  </td>
  <td data-campo="endereco">
    endereço2
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-campo="nome">
    nome3
  </td>
  <td data-campo="email">
    email3
  </td>
  <td data-campo="endereco">
    endereço3
  </td>
</tr>

</table>

<button id="enviar">
enviar
</button>
```

NOTA que deve ajustar as keys (`data-campo`) de cada um, para não serem repetidas

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/hk0pwfnt/8/) no jsfiddle

Comment: Este é para toda a tabela. O outro é para a linha só